# Is is possible to create Linux portable applications?

Tags: portable

I would like to create a set of portable network utils that can be easily loaded in a system (I will have root access) and then deleted quickly

Is this possible?

Here are the apps that I planning to make portable
http://linoxide.com/monitoring-2/network-monitoring-tools-linux/

Comment: I believe that if you compile them yourself from source and modify the file paths in the original code, you should be able to do that. Never tried such a thing though and I don't know whether there are simpler approaches.

Comment: I'm migrating this to U&L since it really isn't about Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

Let's list the reasons, why upon running on some other GNU/Linux distro, an app wouldn't work:

- Missing shared libraries
- Shared libraries of the wrong version
- *(in case you used them)* missing command line utilities
- Breaking change in kernel API

To fight the problem with libs you can simply link everything statically upon build. It would increase the size of the app significantly, but yeah, it'd decrease a number of runtime dependencies.

The command line utilities might be fought by targeting some specific standard, [e.g. POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/contents.html).

You can't fight a change in kernel API though, but it is *(the userspace part)* very stable anyway — stable enough that you may simply not worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So your suggestion is "compile them from source and link everything statically" Correct ? That might not be that simple for me (I am a network engineer not a Linux guy) but I could try.

Comment: @MiniMe Not all apps behave as static compiled either - that's another consideration.

Comment: @MiniMe I thought that compile from a source is exactly what you wanted, like, hacking into it's internals, perhaps for fun. Well, if you aren't, you could probably also try just list dependencies of the executables with `ldd` and then copy every shared library into a single directory, along with binaries. But I should say, I don't know if run-time linker looks in the same directory, so you probably have to experiment with this a bit.

Comment: @Hi-Angel that is doable and I can test it! Thank